# Optimizing PHP while loop

Tags: php, loops, mysqli, while-loop

**What I'm doing:**

Retrieving available apartment listings and grouping them by layout - Studio, 1 Bedroom, 2 Bedroom, etc. Each layout lists the lowest and highest square footage, lowest rent, and then lists out all the individual units with details on each one. I attached an image to demonstrate what it looks like.
[image: floorplans]

**Problem**

Currently, I am using multiple queries to grab the amound of beds and running while loops for each query. I would like this to be optimized and use only 1 query but am not sure where to begin.

**Code**

I am only showing the loops for the Studio and 1 Bedroom here, but I am doing the same thing for 2 and 3 bedroom queries. I would like to consolidate these all to one. Any help is appreciated.

```
$studioQuery = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM properties WHERE Beds = "0" AND PropertyId = '.$propID.' AND AvailableDate <> "" ORDER BY FloorplanName');
$oneBedQuery = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM properties WHERE Beds = "1" AND PropertyId = '.$propID.' AND AvailableDate <> "" ORDER BY FloorplanName');
$twoBedQuery = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM properties WHERE Beds = "2" AND PropertyId = '.$propID.' AND AvailableDate <> "" ORDER BY FloorplanName');
$threeBedQuery = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM properties WHERE Beds = "3" AND PropertyId = '.$propID.' AND AvailableDate <> "" ORDER BY FloorplanName');

// Studio
if($studioQuery->num_rows > 0) {
    echo '<div class="layout">';
    $studioCount = 0;
    $highSqFt = 0;
    $markupStudio = '';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($studioQuery)) {

        $aptID = $row['ApartmentId'];

        // Get the lowest square footage
        if($studioCount == 0){
            $lowSqFt = $row['SQFT'];
            $lowRent = $row['MinimumRent'];
        }
        if($lowSqFt > $row['SQFT']){
            $lowSqFt = $row['SQFT'];
        }
        // Get the highest square footage
        if($highSqFt < $row['SQFT']){
            $highSqFt = $row['SQFT'];
        }
        // Get the lowest Rent
        if($lowRent > $row['MinimumRent']){
            $lowRent = $row['MinimumRent'];
        }

        $markupStudio .= '<div class="row unit">';
        $markupStudio .= '<div class="col-sm-15">'. $row['Beds'] .' Bed / '. $row['Baths'] .' Bath</div>';
        $markupStudio .= '<div class="col-sm-15">'. $row['ApartmentName'] .'</div>';
        $markupStudio .= '<div class="col-sm-15">$'. $row['MinimumRent'] .'</div>';
        $markupStudio .= '<div class="col-sm-15">'. $row['AvailableDate'] .'</div>';
        $markupStudio .= '<div class="col-sm-15 apply-col"><a href="'. $row['ApplyOnlineURL'] .'" target="_blank">Apply ></a></div>';
        $markupStudio .= '</div>';

        $studioCount++;
    }
    ?>

    <div class="row floorplan-header">
        <div class="col-sm-3"><div><h3>Studio</h3></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 sq-ft-col"><div><?php echo $lowSqFt .' - '. $highSqFt .' SQ. FT.'; ?></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 from-price-col"><div>FROM $<?php echo $lowRent; ?></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 available-col"><div>Check Availability <span class="icon-caret-right"></span></div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row unit-list">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="row unit-header">
                <div class="col-sm-15">Type</div>
                <div class="col-sm-15">Unit#</div>
                <div class="col-sm-15">Rent</div>
                <div class="col-sm-15">Available</div>
            </div>
            <?php echo $markupStudio; ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php echo '</div>';
}

// 1 Bedroom
if($oneBedQuery->num_rows > 0) {
    echo '<div class="layout">';
    $oneBedCount = 0;
    $highSqFt = 0;
    $markupOne = '';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($oneBedQuery)) {

        $aptID = $row['ApartmentId'];

        // Get the lowest square footage
        if($oneBedCount == 0){
            $lowSqFt = $row['SQFT'];
            $lowRent = $row['MinimumRent'];
        }
        if($lowSqFt > $row['SQFT']){
            $lowSqFt = $row['SQFT'];
        }
        // Get the highest square footage
        if($highSqFt < $row['SQFT']){
            $highSqFt = $row['SQFT'];
        }
        // Get the lowest Rent
        if($lowRent > $row['MinimumRent']){
            $lowRent = $row['MinimumRent'];
        }

        $markupOne .= '<div class="row unit">';
        $markupOne .= '<div class="col-sm-15">'. $row['Beds'] .' Bed / '. $row['Baths'] .' Bath</div>';
        $markupOne .= '<div class="col-sm-15">'. $row['ApartmentName'] .'</div>';
        $markupOne .= '<div class="col-sm-15">$'. $row['MinimumRent'] .'</div>';
        $markupOne .= '<div class="col-sm-15">'. $row['AvailableDate'] .'</div>';
        $markupOne .= '<div class="col-sm-15 apply-col"><a href="'. $row['ApplyOnlineURL'] .'" target="_blank">Apply ></a></div>';
        $markupOne .= '</div>';

        $oneBedCount++;
    }
    ?>

    <div class="row floorplan-header">
        <div class="col-sm-3"><div><h3>1 Bedroom</h3></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 sq-ft-col"><div><?php echo $lowSqFt .' - '. $highSqFt .' SQ. FT.'; ?></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 from-price-col"><div>FROM $<?php echo $lowRent; ?></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 available-col"><div>Check Availability <span class="icon-caret-right"></span></div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row unit-list">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="row unit-header">
                <div class="col-sm-15">Type</div>
                <div class="col-sm-15">Unit#</div>
                <div class="col-sm-15">Rent</div>
                <div class="col-sm-15">Available</div>
            </div>
            <?php echo $markupOne; ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php echo '</div>';
}
```

/*** Edit ***/

So now I have the one query but my logic is off in the while loop. It is now printing out the correct amount of Floorplan headers, but is only showing the first available unit under 1 Bedroom and then it's listing all of the available 1 Bedroom units under the 2 Bedroom header and only the first available 2 Bedroom unit. Below is the updated code.

```
$bedQuery = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM properties WHERE PropertyId = '.$propID.' AND AvailableDate <> "" ORDER BY Beds, FloorplanName');

// Floorplans
if($bedQuery->num_rows > 0) {

    $bedCount = 0;
    $highSqFt = 0;
    $markup = '';
    $previous = 0;

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($bedQuery)) {

        $bedCount = $row['Beds'];
        $aptID = $row['ApartmentId'];

        // Get the lowest square footage
        if($previous == 0){
            $lowSqFt = $row['SQFT'];
            $lowRent = $row['MinimumRent'];
        }
        if($lowSqFt > $row['SQFT']){
            $lowSqFt = $row['SQFT'];
        }
        // Get the highest square footage
        if($highSqFt < $row['SQFT']){
            $highSqFt = $row['SQFT'];
        }
        // Get the lowest Rent
        if($lowRent > $row['MinimumRent']){
            $lowRent = $row['MinimumRent'];
        }

        $markup .= '<div class="row unit">';
        $markup .= '<div class="col-sm-15">'. $row['Beds'] .' Bed / '. $row['Baths'] .' Bath</div>';
        $markup .= '<div class="col-sm-15">'. $row['ApartmentName'] .'</div>';
        $markup .= '<div class="col-sm-15">$'. $row['MinimumRent'] .'</div>';
        $markup .= '<div class="col-sm-15">'. $row['AvailableDate'] .'</div>';
        $markup .= '<div class="col-sm-15 apply-col"><a href="'. $row['ApplyOnlineURL'] .'" target="_blank">Apply ></a></div>';
        $markup .= '</div>';

        if($bedCount != $previous) {
            //echo 'Beds: '.$bedCount.'</br>';
            //echo 'Previous: '.$previous;
            echo '<div class="layout">';
        ?>

        <div class="row floorplan-header">
            <div class="col-sm-3"><div><h3><?php echo $row['Beds']; ?> Bedroom</h3></div></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 sq-ft-col"><div><?php echo $lowSqFt .' - '. $highSqFt .' SQ. FT.'; ?></div></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 from-price-col"><div>FROM $<?php echo $lowRent; ?></div></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 available-col"><div>Check Availability <span class="icon-caret-right"></span></div></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row unit-list">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="row unit-header">
                    <div class="col-sm-15">Type</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-15">Unit#</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-15">Rent</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-15">Available</div>
                </div>
                <?php echo $markup; ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php echo '</div>';
        }

        $previous = $bedCount;

    }

}
```

Comment: Look into `group by`

Comment: @developerwjk I dont think `GROUP BY` is of much use here because he wants all the individual entries he just wants them with a single query.

Answer (score 3):

Your one query would result from using `in()` and adding `Beds` to the `order by`:

```
$studioQuery = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM properties WHERE Beds IN('0','1','2','3') AND PropertyId = '.$propID.' AND AvailableDate <> "" ORDER BY Beds, FloorplanName');
```

Now in the same query you will get all the rows you want, with each Bed number coming before the next, and in each Bed amount you will have it ordered by FloorplanName.

Now, simply as you loop through them, keep track of last Bed value and compare to current bed value.  When they are no longer equal, print your new header for that section.

Comment: The `IN` isn't neccessary here... I think he only had the `WHERE` clause in order to divide them up into sections, now that he gets all the data at once it becomes unneeded. its the `ORDER BY` that makes the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the reponses. I am now using a single query but my logic is off. I  made an edit to the originial post to show the updated code.

Comment: @downtomike Before `if($bedCount != $previous) {` you forgot to set `$bedCount = $rows['Bed'];`

Comment: @downtomike And take out `$bedCount++;` That var should be set by `$bedCount = $rows['Bed'];` at the very top of the loop.

Comment: Okay I am getting closer to finishing this. I updated my code example and explained what is happening now, but basically it is printing out the correct amount of headers but the listings under each aren't correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making one query to select all the data, then save it into an array indexed on number of beds.

Then iterate the individual top level elements in place of your current while loops

```
$query = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM properties WHERE Beds < 4 AND PropertyId = '.$propID.' AND AvailableDate <> "" ORDER BY FloorplanName');

$data=[];

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    $data[$row['beds']][]=$row;

foreach($data[0] as $studioRow)
    //studio code


foreach($data[1] as $oneBedRow)
    //onebed code
```

This minimizes your refactoring and helps separate your presentation from your logic a little bit